# About learning c#

Tags: unity, c#

I am a high school student. I know different languages like c, c++(70%), html, python (half). Now I want to learn c# for unity development. I want to learn it from the very beginning and I have 1 year to learn C# perfectly.I found different ways to learn it but don't know which is the best....

1. Solo learn mobile app "Learn c#" / [www.sololearn.com](http://www.sololearn.com) are same
2. Tutorial points PDF...( pages near 330)
3. Youtube channels

Comment: We dont really house questions like this, but Id simply recommend doing unity c# tutorials (note that unityscript is javascript, not c#). I just completed sololearn for the lols, and can tell you it can be very useful, you just want to practice. Note that challenge questions are user submitted; they can sometimes be wrong, so do not rely on challenge mode for practice. As a last note, c# is a lot easier than c++. You may find it easier having that under your belt

Comment: thanks, but I choosed c# for unity development instead of java script...( I have no experience with unity development) I taught C# is easier than java...

Comment: My point is, you tagged this with unityscript. If you go looking for unityscript, you wont find c#.

Comment: Do not confuse [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) with [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Comment: Unless you code 16 hours a day, programming different things, _"have 1 year to learn C# perfectly." is not going to happen. You don't become a senior dev in 1 year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a typical question you should ask in here, but since your target is to learn C# for unity development, I would suggest starting with the "unity tailored" [Scripting tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting). They are pretty basic and you should go through them with ease. from there on you could advance from a lot of references throughout the web. But starting with the mentioned tutorials is most recommended since it puts you on the track so you know what you want to look for later.

Hope this helps.

Comment: _"this is not a typical question you should ask in here"_ Please avoid answering these :)

Comment: oh, ok!! noted :)

Comment: thanks...but I am only starter of c# console application at sololearn...can I start learning unity gameplay scripting leaving sololearns basic concepts?

Comment: yeah, even if so. You will surely gain some valuable info this way. happy things are going fine for you.